# How can ffmpeg stream a never-ending video file to RTMP

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, avi

I currently have an issue publishing a constantly appended video file to RTMP.
My workflow is

- I proxy the `MediaSource` class in the browser.
- From this I upload every byte appended to the buffers in a self hosted server
- The server finally appends the `video.avi` file.

I want to stream that constantly updated avi file to an RTMP endpoint.
The issue I encounter is that `ffmpeg` will stop streaming the file once it has reached the duration it had when launching `ffmpeg`.

I don't know much about streaming videos and if it can be done "just" by appending an avi file.
The command I'm using is

`.\ffmpeg.exe -re -i .\file.avi -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/STREAM_NAME`

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Use a pipe or a fifo instead of a regular like.

Comment: @szatmary I am using a writeStream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `ffmpeg` supports reading through FIFO. Now I'm creating a fifo instead of a regular file and just append my data in it.

Thanks to @szatmary for the tip